# QGIS Atlas Grouping Features by Attribute

Tags: qgis, atlas

I've got the Atlas function down (AWESOME!) and am generating maps for every feature.

What I need to do now is generate maps for groups of features based on a shared attribute.

```
fid | name | group
01  | a    | 1
02  | b    | 1
03  | c    | 2
04  | d    | 2
```

Essentially, two maps, one with "zoom to extent" for all group 1 features, and the other zoomed to extent for all group 2 features.

Is possible?

Comment: Similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244184/qgis-atlas-generation-for-multiple-map-extents/340932

Comment: @Vincet Dulout can explain a little bit more your last instruction (..and set style to...)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most elegant, but here's the steps I took to solve this:

1. Create a new multi-polygon layer with "Name" attribute.
2. Draw bounding boxes around the groups of features and name it after the group (Automated with tool: `minimum bounding geometry`)
3. Set the Atlas to "Hidden Coverage Layer" using the bounding layer just created.
4. To highlight the features (bonus!): Set the atlas pagename to the Name attribute of the bounding box layer, then set the style of the features layer "Rule Based" and `"Group" = $atlas_pagename`

Comment: See if the `concave hull` and `convex hull` algorithms accept a grouping parameter. If they do you can use one of them instead of drawing bounding boxes manually.

Comment: Those don't but the tool: `minimum bounding geometry` does. Man I LOVE QGIS!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I did an other way:

1- In `Vector ‣ Geoprocessing Tools`, use the `dissolve` function

In your case you will select the common attributes as your group.

This will create a new layer, e.g. 'dissolve_layer', with a single polygon by group.

more info here : https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=regrouper#dissolve

2 - Set your atlas : using the new layer'dissolve_layer' as coverage layer and hidde it, and set style to your original layer such as  "group" =attribute (@atlas_feature, 'group')